# Query Azure time series data(TSI) data

Tags: javascript, azure

How can i use the [Azure TSI query API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-reference-queryapi) to get data exact data out of TSI. I am using TSI JavaScript Client library that has two wrapper on top of Query API. Those wrappers only allow me to get aggregate data such as sum, min, max etc. But i want the real time data and not aggregate data because I have to apply Fourier transform on it. 
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Get Events" API with mandatory searchSpan and Limit clauses.
Refer the [offical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/gen1-query-api#get-environment-events-api) for details.

However be prepared to process two JSON arrays, one for property name/index and other for actual values, to get required information.